# Do my user need to install a database program to use my database program?

Tags: c#, database, embedded-database

This might be a stupid question but I'm new at all this.

I want to create a Windows program that communicates with a database. Is there any way to do this without the user of my program have to install a database program like MySql?

I'm going to program it in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use embedded databases like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or Firebird Embedded.

You can find the full list of embedded database solutions on [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) works for you. But it doesn't support some functionalities. But you don't need to install a seperate database server. It works embedded.

Comment: I added a link to the SQL Server Compact page in your answer.  I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention MySQL: [MySQL Embedded Database](http://www.mysql.com/oem/)

(It's not free, though.)